# How can I use json inside my resources folder?

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I'm using Visual Studio with Xamarin and wish to store a json file inside of my resources folder.

I need to get the path, deserialize it, then load the data asynchronously. I've looked around, but can't find any useful examples. Is this possible?

Comment: What should be in the json file? Please specify your purpose

Comment: my json file contains a list of descriptions.. I wish to use it to pass data on my detail activity..

Comment: if you need serilizable your json to object class you can use this website http://json2csharp.com/ then pass it via intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the file under the "Assets" folder and use the following code to access it:

```
// to read from assets folder 
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("file.json")))
{
   content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}

// JSON is now in "content"
```

Afterwards you can pass the string to a JSON parser. You can find more information on this topic in the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/) (=> Reading assets).

Comment: He wants to read the file from the resources/assets folder. I don't think *System.IO.File.ReadAllText* will be suitable here.

Comment: let me know if you need help , if you want my advice forget json file and store your object inside database for fast retrieve

Comment: here is link to tutorial https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/ , you can contact me any time for any help needed check my profile for my contact details

Comment: thank you sir.. I'll surely email you when I need help :D